# Convert trial account to persistent?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a trial account and am ready to move it to a "live" instance that will persist and be billed to me but I am unable to determine how to do this? When/how/where do I tell Snowflake how to bill me and know that the instance will continue to persist after e.g. 30 days.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you wish to continue using the Snowflake trial account, you need to add credit card details to the account.

This will convert your trial account to On-Demand(Pay-As-You-Go).

You can find the details: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/admin-trial-account.html#adding-a-credit-card-to-a-trial-account

Comment: For some reason I cannot see the "Billing" link. I'll resolve that separately but I think this is the right answer.

Thanks a lot for pointing me in the right direction.